# Break Up Array and output to table?

Tags: php, arrays

I run a gaming server and it keeps some information in a database.
I run a MySQL query that pulls information like cargo_items (below).
How can I format this data properly in PHP?  I'd like for it to be in a table.  Is that possible?  My knowledge of handing arrays like this is limited do to the complex nature.  This is how the data is returned from the database.

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => Array
   (
     [0] => Array
     (
       [id] => 2237
       [cargo_weapons] =>      
       [
         ["MMG_02_black_F","","","",[],""],
         ["arifle_SDAR_F","","","",[],""],
         ["arifle_SDAR_F","","","",[],""],        
         ["arifle_SPAR_03_khk_F","","","",[],""],
         ["LMG_Zafir _F","","","",[],""],
         ["MMG_02_black_F","","","",[],""],
         ["MMG_02_black_F","","","",[],""]
       ]
     )
   )
 )
```

The output should be a table:

```
 Weapons
 -------
 MMG_02_black_F
 arifle_SDAR_F
 arifle_SDAR_F
 arifle_SPAR_03_khk_F
 LMG_Zafir_F
 MMG_02_black_F
 MMG_02_black_F
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I don't have anything that works.  I don't know how to handle the empty entries in the array.

Comment: Then show us how the information should be displayed as a result

Comment: I added it above and edited the original

Comment: You can use `empty()` or `array_filter()` inside the loop. Or may be `array_column()` can help. Depends.

Comment: basically, i just need everything that is inside "" and put it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multidimensional array, you need custom recursion function, or, **in your specific case**, you could use something like this:

```
function get_items($item, $key)
{
    if(!empty($item) && $key=='cargo_weapons')
    //your html table cells
    echo "$item<br>";
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'get_items');
```

[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

will do the job (this function returns true or false), but you can (ab)use it to display desired HTML too.